# Detect which class was clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to find out which element was clicked when there are multiple elements on the same page with the same class.

The class which is clicked I then want to show but keep all the other classes hidden.

```
<div class="btn"> 
   <div class="btn-content">
      <p>1,2,3,4,5</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="btn"> 
   <div class="btn-content">
      <p>1,2,3,4,5</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery -

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   $(".btn-content").show();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `this` to find the element in current context:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
 $(this).find(".btn-content").show();// or  $(".btn-content",this).show()
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxmsS/)**

Comment: ah, I did look for a .this function must have missed it thank you I will try

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   $(this).find(".btn-content").show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/gJrpk/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can find the element with class .btn-content to show only has clicked.
Use find jQuery function for that

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
  $(this).find(".btn-content").show();
});
```